# How to escape characters from a single command?

Tags: bash, sed

How do I escape characters in linux using the sed command?

I want to print something like this

```
echo hey$ya
```

But I'm just receiving a

```
hey
```

how can escape the $ character?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are only seing "hey" echoed is that because of the `$`, the shell tries to expand a variable called `ya`.  Since no such variable exists, it expands to an empty string (basically it disappears).

You can use single quotes, they prevent variable expansion :

```
echo 'hey$ya'
```

You can also escape the character :

```
echo hey\$ya
```

Strings can also be enclosed in double quotes (e.g. `echo "hey$ya"`), but these do not prevent expansion, all they do is keep the whole expression as a single string instead of allowing word splitting to separate words in separate arguments for the command being executed.  Using double quotes would not work in your case.

Comment: You can also do `echo "hey$"ya` though using single quotes is the best option here.

Comment: I'm using sed to do it. When I run the command ib the console it works but when I add it to a script fails. Do you know why would this be happening? :(

Comment: @Lost When you way "I'm using sed to do it", can you describe what you are using sed to do?

Comment: I have a variable exported in my ~/.bashrc file like this: `export var=this$value` and I want to use it on a script but when I echo it I get only "this". So I did this:
 `newValue=$(echo $var | sed -e 's/[()&#%$+]/\\&/g')` but whenever I print `newValue` I get only`"this" instead of "this$value"

Answer (score 0):

`\` is the escape character. So your example would be:

```
~ » echo hey\$ya
hey$ya
~ »
```